# Android Convert WGS84 altitude to MSL offline

Tags: android, location, wgs84, altitude

After 2 hours of researching I didn't find a suitable solution for my problem. I want to get the accurate altitude of a smartphone within my app. I understand that I get the altitude dependent on the WGS84 and I also understand that I have to subtract/add the geoid height. But where do I get the geoid height for my current Location?

Thanks in advance
Philipp

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As this is a very geographic data specific question you may be better off asking at [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=msl)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's less a problem of converting those, but more about getting the data set into my android application?

Comment: As written the question appears to ask "where can I find X data". But the gist of your problem may be similar to [Is Android's GPS altitude incorrect due to not including geoid height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11168306/295004) which has further references to investigate.

Comment: I already read this thread but the solution only explains from where the difference comes from, and not how I can get the dataset to calculate the Real height within my android app